# Why does my Android application not returning if connection to Apache is available?

Tags: android, connection

I have an android application and I want it to check if the IP Address entered by the user is available, or can be connected to, or has an Apache instance from which I would load php files.

Here is my code on the java file of the activity :

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IPAddress extends Activity {


    String ip;
    String error = "";  

    Boolean next = false;

    EditText ipaddress1;
    EditText ipaddress2;
    EditText ipaddress3;
    EditText ipaddress4;
    Button connect;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ipaddress);

        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);


        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ipaddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress1);
                    ipaddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress2);
                    ipaddress3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress3);
                    ipaddress4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress4);

                    ip = ipaddress1.getText().toString() +"."+ipaddress2.getText().toString()+"."+ipaddress3.getText().toString()+"."+ipaddress4.getText().toString();
                    new checkIPAddress().execute("");

                }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ipaddress, menu);
        return true;
    }

     /**
     * Background Async Task to Insert IP address
     * */
    class checkIPAddress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(IPAddress.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * check ipaddress connection in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    pDialog.setMessage("Checking connection. Please wait...");
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // CHECK IF USER HAS WIFI ENABLED
                    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(ip);
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

                            Log.d("Response", response.toString() +"--response from apache");
                            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                                next = true;
                            } else {
                                next = false;
                                error = "Please check entered IP Address";
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            next = false;
                            error = "Please check entered IP Address";                          
                        }
                    } else {
                            next = false;
                            error = "No Internet connections available";
                    }


                    // CHECK IF USER CAN CONNECT TO APACHE SERVER

                    Log.d("IP Address", ip);

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("NEXT VALUE --in Async on postexecute", next +"");
            if(next == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(IPAddress.this, "Connection succesful." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent (IPAddress.this, ChooseTable.class);
                i.putExtra("IP_Address", ip);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(IPAddress.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my LogCat :

```
02-07 00:03:30.011: V/TLINE(668): new: android.text.TextLine@4066afd0
02-07 00:03:32.542: V/TLINE(668): new: android.text.TextLine@40674158
02-07 00:04:09.382: D/dalvikvm(668): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 163K, 5% free 6483K/6791K, paused 236ms
02-07 00:04:09.448: I/dalvikvm-heap(668): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.929MB for 513744-byte allocation
02-07 00:04:09.962: D/dalvikvm(668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 5% free 6983K/7303K, paused 35ms+64ms
02-07 00:04:11.352: W/System.err(668): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.10.149
02-07 00:04:11.393: W/System.err(668):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-07 00:04:11.393: W/System.err(668):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-07 00:04:11.402: W/System.err(668):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-07 00:04:11.415: W/System.err(668):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-07 00:04:11.422: W/System.err(668):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-07 00:04:11.422: W/System.err(668):  at com.thesis.menubook.IPAddress$checkIPAddress$1.run(IPAddress.java:99)
02-07 00:04:11.437: W/System.err(668):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 00:04:11.442: W/System.err(668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 00:04:11.442: W/System.err(668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-07 00:04:11.462: W/System.err(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-07 00:04:11.462: W/System.err(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 00:04:11.462: W/System.err(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-07 00:04:11.482: W/System.err(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-07 00:04:11.482: W/System.err(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-07 00:04:11.492: W/System.err(668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 00:04:11.492: D/IP Address(668): 192.168.10.149
02-07 00:04:11.503: D/NEXT VALUE --in Async on postexecute(668): false
```

I have Apache on my laptop up and running and I can connect to it using this laptop's browser and my android phone's browser using this laptop's IP Address. I am running the application on an emulator. My Anti Virus also does not have a firewall or network shield. And I have opened ports on my laptop's firewall. I have also tried running the application and including the port on the `ip` string, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

in your call...

```
  new checkIPAddress().execute("");
```

you should pass in the IP Address you are interested in checking...

```
  new checkIPAddress().execute(ip);
```

and reference it in `doInBackground()` as `params[0]`. You should not be referencing any external variables in the `AsyncTask` class. If you need to update the UI, do that in `onPostExecute()`. It is really odd to see `runOnUIThread` in the `onBackground()` function. UI interaction, again, should be placed in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: `params[0]` will contain the `ip` string. Check it in the debugger!

Comment: are you passing it in on the `checkIPAddress().execute(new String[] { ip });` line????

Comment: i just checked my code. try `checkIPAddress().execute(ip);` that's what i do...reference by `params[0]`. sorry

Comment: you should not be using any external variables in your `AsyncTask` only what is passed into `AsyncTask`. you should remove the `runOnUiThread` block (AsyncTask already runs in a Thread). Any UI updates should take place in `onPostExecute()`.